# Downloading metadata from quandl.com with python, and getting no values with my fields?

Tags: python, quandl

I copied this code from quandl.com. I want to get the dataset specifics like is this data set data frequency Daily, Weekly, or Monthly. When I run the code I get the field names but no values, but if I try to load a csv file from quandl directly with out using python then I get what I need. I am not for sure why this won't work in python??

This is the code copied from https://www.quandl.com/docs/api?python#get-metadata

```
import quandl

metadata = quandl.Dataset("BOE/XUDLADS").data_fields()

print(metadata)
```

This is my output

```
['refreshed_at', 'premium', 'id', 'name', 'database_code', 'newest_available_date', 'frequency', 'description', 'oldest_available_date', 'type', 'column_names', 'dataset_code', 'database_id']
```

I get the field names but no values

when I just use this link, and not python I get exactly what I need
https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB/metadata.csv"

My ultimate goal is to store this metadata in a python dict()

Comment: That's exactly what the documentation (to which you provided a link) says you should get, using the `.data_fields()` method.

Comment: `metadata = quandl.Dataset("BOE/XUDLADS").data().meta`.

Comment: metadata = quandl.Dataset("BOE/XUDLADS").data().meta works thankyou how do I give you credit for this answer??

Comment: @ZacAttack, I added it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata is an attribute of the `data` itself. So you will have to get the data and then get to the metadata, as follows:

```
metadata = quandl.Dataset("BOE/XUDLADS").data().meta
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Abdou's answer is helpful, but I found that several of the metadata fields I was after (e.g. `name` and `description`) instead had to be accessed as attributes of the Dataset:

(from [the docs](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python/blob/master/FOR_DEVELOPERS.md))

> Note that a call to any attribute such as name will trigger an API metadata call if the metadata has not been loaded yet.

```
dataset = quandl.Dataset('WIKI/AAPL')
name = dataset.name
description = dataset.description
```